# Lexical vs dynamic scoping in terms of SICP's Environment Model of Evaluation

Tags: scheme, sicp, lexical-scope, dynamic-scope

In [Section 3.2.2](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-21.html#%_sec_3.2.2) of SICP the execution of the following piece of code

```
(define (square x)
  (* x x))
(define (sum-of-squares x y)
  (+ (square x) (square y)))
(define (f a)
  (sum-of-squares (+ a 1) (* a 2)))

(f 5)
```

is explained in terms of [this diagram](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/ch3-Z-G-6.gif).

Each time a function is applied, a new frame is created (labeled by `E1` through `E4`)  which represents a set of bindings between symbols and values. When a symbol is not bound in a frame, that frame's enclosing environment is queried for a binding of that particular symbol.

The interesting thing about this diagram is that all the frames labelled by `E` is contained in the global environment. The text explains that this is because the functions was defined in the global environment, but does not elaborate on the issue:

> Notice that each frame created by `square` points to the global environment, since this is the environment indicated by the `square` procedure object.

If instead frames where contained in the environment that the function was called in, say `E3` was contained in `E2` which in turn was contained in `E1`, would that be a valid model of how a dynamically scoped language works? Also, is the way that the frames in the diagram have the same 'parent' environment because Scheme is lexically scoped?

Answer (score 6):

The answer to both questions is **yes**.  That chapter of SICP is explaining lexical scope without actually using the term.  Changing the evaluation mechanism as you describe would create a dynamically-scoped model.